# What determines whether packer buffers stdout

Tags: go, packer, buffering

I invoke packer from python Popen as

```
proc = Popen(['packer', 'build', '.'], stdout=PIPE, encoding='utf8')
for o in proc.stdout:
    do_stuff_with(o)
```

Sometimes `do_stuff_with` gets called frequently while `packer build` does things.  Sometimes it doesn't -- just once at the end with all the content.  The effect is deterministic based on how I invoke the python, but not in a way that makes sense.

I've confirmed with perf events that when the call come frequently, packer is sending `sched_wakeup` to python, and when they don't it isn't.  So I'm convinced that packer's status updates are buffering somewhere *inside* packer before going to stdout.

Packer is written in go.  Its output code is a maze of twisty dead links and thin wrappers, all alike, so I can't figure out if the printing of status messages bottoms out in fmt.Printf or what.

Does anyone know what controls whether or not packer flushes its stdout buffer every line?

Comment: Are you sure output goes to stdout and not stderr?

Comment: @jdizzle: if the output went to stderr, `proc.stdout` would be empty as only `stdout` is captured in the `PIPE` here.

Comment: Go has no buffering *by default*, so it's up to whoever does the writing to choose how to do buffering. People may insert `bufio` wrappers around stdout, or do all kinds of crazy things; it's hard to tell without having access to the source.

Comment: Can you please describe the two contexts (python invocations if I understand correctly) that trigger the two different behaviors ?